# Replacement AC adapter models: PA 1650 02 and T UV 19 35

Tags: laptop, adapter, charger

I'd like to know whether the one adapter can safely replace the other.

The original was a LiteOn model: PA-1650-02 Input: 100-240v 1.6A 50-60Hz Output: 19v 3.42A 65w

Although I thought I was purchasing the same model, I received something different.

T Power Model: T-UV-19-35 Input: 100-240v 50-60hz 1.0-1.5A Output: 18v-20v 2A-4A

Is it the sort of thing where close enough works? I'm not sure how these things function and a Google search didn't provide much information. Is anyone knowledgeable? Responses are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's safe, the power output rating is between 2-4 V (which is in the range of the original) and the Amp's are in the range as well.

Power adapter ratings explain the amount of power it can HANDLE, not what it gives directly. Your 'input' means the adapter itself takes the 100-240v AC line using 1.5 amps and converts to DC current with a *potential* to deliver between 18-20V at a rating of 2-4A meaning it can handle a total load of between 36-80 W without delivering more power than is required to the device (probably through some sort of line/noise filters/etc).

Mind you the quality of the parts in the adapters can make a difference, but generally at the wattage ratings your dealing with you should be ok.

Always try plugging in the new adapter with the power off first (if you haven't already started using it)

Comment: Glad I could help :)